# group_concat_max_length system variable not changed even after changing my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, group-concat, my.cnf

I have currently installed MySQL version `5.6` installed on my local system. I want to permanently set the `group_concat_max_length` system variable to some value.
When I do it using 
       `set global group_concat_max_len = 100000;`
 command in the mysql terminal, the value is set but the value changes to default on restart.
I have also changed `my.cnf` file and put it under `[mysqld]` header.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Edit:
my.cnf

```
    #
    # The MySQL database server configuration file.
    #
    # You can copy this to one of:
    # - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
    # - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
    #
    # One can use all long options that the program supports.
    # Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
    # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
    #
    # For explanations see
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

    # This will be passed to all mysql clients
    # It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
    # escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
    # Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
    [client]
    port        = 3306
    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    # Here is entries for some specific programs
    # The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

    # This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
    [mysqld_safe]
    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    nice        = 0

    [mysqld]
    #
    # * Basic Settings
    #
    user        = mysql
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port        = 3306
    basedir        = /usr
    datadir        = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir        = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir    = /usr/share/mysql
    skip-external-locking
    #
    # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    # bind-address        = 127.0.0.1


    #max_connections=200 (mysql connections)
    #
    # * Fine Tuning
    #
    key_buffer        = 16M
    max_allowed_packet    = 16M
    thread_stack        = 192K
    thread_cache_size       = 8
    # This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
    # the first time they are touched
    myisam-recover         = BACKUP
    #max_connections        = 100
    #table_cache            = 64
    #thread_concurrency     = 10
    #
    # * Query Cache Configuration
    #

    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
    query_cache_size=268435456
    query_cache_type=1
    query_cache_limit=8388608
    group_concat_max_len=100000

    #query_cache_limit    = 1M
    #query_cache_size        = 16M

    #
    # * Logging and Replication
    #
    # Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
    # Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
    # As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
    #general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    #general_log             = 1
    #
    # Error log - should be very few entries.
    #
    log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
    #
    # Here you can see queries with especially long duration
    #log_slow_queries    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
    #long_query_time = 2
    #log-queries-not-using-indexes
    #
    # The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
    # note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
    #       other settings you may need to change.
    #server-id        = 1
    #log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
    expire_logs_days    = 10
    max_binlog_size         = 100M
    #binlog_do_db        = include_database_name
    #binlog_ignore_db    = include_database_name
    #
    # * InnoDB
    #
    # InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
    # Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
    #
    # * Security Features
    #
    # Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
    # chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
    #
    # For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
    #
    # ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
    # ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
    # ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



    [mysqldump]
    quick
    quote-names
    max_allowed_packet    = 16M

    [mysql]
    #no-auto-rehash    # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

    [isamchk]
    key_buffer        = 16M

    #
    # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
    #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
    #
    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

mysql file in /etc/init.d/

```
    ...
    SELF=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd -P)/$(basename $0)
    CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"

    # priority can be overriden and "-s" adds output to stderr
    ERR_LOGGER="logger -p daemon.err -t /etc/init.d/mysql -i"
    ...
```

After mysql restart:

```
    mysql> show variables like '%group_concat_max%';
    +----------------------+-------+
    | Variable_name        | Value |
    +----------------------+-------+
    | group_concat_max_len | 1024  |
    +----------------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You probably typed it wrong in my.cnf. Can you check mysql logs to see if there is anything about it ? And please paste your my.cnf here. Also where exactly is your my.cnf ?

Comment: @abeyaz it is in /etc/mysql/ folder.

Comment: If you are sure that it goes back to default value even though you have 100000 in the my.cnf file, mysql probably doesnt see your my.cnf file in that directory. Can you check `/etc/init.d/mysql` if you are using debian/ubuntu based distro, there will be location of my.cnf there

Comment: @abeyaz can you suggest me what to change in this? I really have no idea about this.

Comment: Looks like it is correct. You shouldn't change it. Now please, run `sudo service mysql restart` and then connect to mysql and run `show variables like '%group_concat_max_length%';`. What is the response ?

Comment: `mysql> show variables like '%group_concat_max_len%';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| group_concat_max_len | 1024  |
+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Can you put all the configs to new lines? In the text you pasted, they are in one line with a space among them.

Comment: I notice you have `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/` at the end of your config file. If there's any config file under your conf.d directory that defines group_concat_max_len to 1024, it will overrule your change. The *last* read setting for an option takes precedence.

Comment: @BillKarwin There are no such configurations that overrides the group_concat_max_len variable

Answer (score 0):

The single line from your configuration file  NEEDS to be listed as 6 lines  because initialization can only deal with one variable per line, imho.

You will likely find that your query cache size of about 268M and query_cache_limit of about 8M would be more effective at 50M and 1M respectively.
The reason being when one row is changed in a table, every cached query result for the updated table is marked invalid - i.e. cpu cycles are consumed to mark the cache results individually.

After restart, please confirm SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_length' has your intended value.  It should be visible.

Comment: It was an indentation issue while pasting the my.cnf file that lead to the initialization look like it was a single line. I have edited my post now. thank you